# Macro expansion in Antlr4

Tags: antlr4

We are developing a modeling tool in which the user can insert small pieces of code in various places. The user can add macros to this code, which we need to expand before parsing the final code. For example, when I parse the following code...

```
FOR i := 6 TO 1 DO 
    j := 6;
    IF SM_MCP.State = oMcpApplication.UNDEFINED
    THEN
        Macro1(MsgNotInZeroPosition);
    END_IF;
END_FOR;
```

... I just want to handle the macro in a visitor function. The result would be:

```
FOR i := 6 TO 1 DO 
    j := 6;
    IF SM_MCP.State = oMcpApplication.UNDEFINED
    THEN
        <ClassName>.MessageQueue := MsgNotInZeroPosition;
    END_IF;
END_FOR;
```

(This is just a made up example.) I have tried to create a simple grammar that parses the macros and simply copies everything around it. But, for some reason I cannot get it working properly.

I have tried several grammars, they all looked something like this:

```
grammar Macros;

source : (code macro )* code ;

macro : macro1 | macro2 | macro3 | macro4 ;
macro1 : Macro1  '(' parameters ')' ;
macro2 : Macro2  '(' parameters ')' ;
macro3 : Macro3  '(' parameters ')' ;
macro4 : Macro4  '(' parameters ')' ;

code : OTHER*  ;
parameters : OTHER*  ;

// Lexer rules

Macro1: 'Macro1';
Macro2: 'Macro2';
Macro3: 'Macro3';
Macro4: 'Macro4';

OTHER : . ;
```

I have tried non-greedy matching too, but most of the times everything ended up in one token or the parser crashed. Can anyone point me in the proper direction?

Answer (score 1):

Your `macro` production shouldn't be using the macro tokens:

```
macro : Macro1 | Macro2 | Macro3 | Macro4 ;
```

but the macro productions:

```
macro : macro1 | macro2 | macro3 | macro4 ;
```

When I change that, your example input gets parsed as follows:

[image]

Comment: Good call. I did it correctly in my proper grammar though. Just a mistake I made in the example. My bad.

Comment: @Tsjakka, check my edit: when I make the change proposed in my answer, it works like a charm.

Comment: Bart, I'm amazed. Sorry I can't reproduce it right now, because I didn't bring my laptop from work. Will try monday.

Comment: I just tried and got the same results. A promising start, thanks for helping. Now, to take it one step further I need to get the code and parameters in one token, not each character in a separate one. Furthermore, it turns out there is code in which variables are used with the same name as macros (but without the '(' behind them). Any tips on how to prevent the parser from thinking it is a macro?

Comment: @Tsjakka, no problem. If you have any further questions, feel free to create a new question. The small comment-boxes are not well suited for extensive Q&A's.